# Manual Thunderbird update in Debian 8 Jessie Linux with Gnome

Tags: debian, thunderbird, software-updates

After manually installing [Mozilla Thunderbird on Debian 8 Jessie according to this instructions](http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/install-thunderbird-in-debian-8/), and it's working fine. However, I cannot update it!

Thunderbird self warns me that an available update could not start automatically. Even manually I've not managed to update it. I've tried this by going to the directory

```
$ /usr/thunderbird
```

and executing the (green [*]) `updater` file(?!).

I'm pretty new to Linux, so please do understand if there might be some lack of termini precision.

[*] `$ ls -la` shows the files in different colors.

Comment: If you're new to linux then always use packages from your distribution only.

Comment: @IporSircer Thank you, I understand your advice. However, I'm coming from Windows->Ubuntu and need Thunderbird which is not offered by Debian.

Comment: `thunderbird` was renamed to `icedove` in debian. it is the same with different name & logo.
1st google hit: https://www.google.com/search?q=debian+thunderbird

Comment: @IporSircer I know this. However -- before installing -- I've read that there might be security and/or compatibility issues with my thunderbird profile (which I've imported/copied from my obsolete system).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create  new apt source under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuzilla.list
```

Import the key:

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
```

Update and install `thunderbird`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

NB:

> [Icedove](https://wiki.debian.org/Icedove) is the Thunderbird email client rebranded by Debian.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :-) I've tried to `echo` the first command but it answers: `Permission denied` (even prefixed with `sudo`). [See here](http://pastebin.com/EJkgQyk6).

Comment: Run it as root or Sudo with root privileges

Comment: could you please provide the code (`su -` maybe?).